# Essential Ideals in non-C*-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, operator-algebras

I am currently trying to show the equivalence of the following two properties in a unital, countable dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $K$ of characteristic zero.

1. The two-sided ideal $I$ is essential in $A$, in that it has non-trivial intersection with any other ideal.
2. For every $a \in A$, if $aI = 0$ then $a = 0$.

There is a similar result Murphy's book $C^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory buried in the discussion before Theorem 3.1.8, but the proof depends on the existence of a positive square root; since I am working with algebras in general, I cannot assume that.

My question is, does this equivalence still work in general algebras. If not, what conditions are needed for equivalence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general.  For instance, let $A=K[t]/(t^2)$.  Then the ideal $I=(t)$ is essential (it is the only nonzero proper ideal), but $tI=0$.

However, the implication $(2\Rightarrow 1)$ is true in any ring and the implication $(1\Rightarrow 2)$ is true in any ring with no nonzero nilpotent elements.  To prove $(2\Rightarrow 1)$, suppose $I$ satisfies (2) and let $J$ be any nonzero ideal.  Then there is some nonzero $a\in J$, and $aI\neq 0$.  Since $aI\subseteq I\cap J$, this means $I\cap J\neq 0$.  Since $J$ was arbitrary, $I$ is essential.

Now suppose $A$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.  Let $I\subseteq A$ be an essential ideal and let $J=\{a\in A:aI=0\}$.  Then $J$ is an ideal, so if $J$ is nontrivial, $I\cap J$ is nontrivial.  But if $a\in I\cap J$, then $a^2\in aI=0$.  Since $A$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, this means $I\cap J=0$, and so $J=0$.